# How to filter users by email from my test database with firebase registered users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase realtime database.
I have some authenticated users and some test users in database.

I can't upload images here due to some reasons.So
Database for authenticated users looks like this in the following url:
https://ibb.co/dBSS8z

And database for testUsers looks like this:
https://ibb.co/dpnoFe

I want to filter Users available in node "testUsers" based on email with users available in node "users" on server side and want to display only those users who are available in testUsers node and  So how can I write cloud-function for it? How to filter users in backend?

Comment: I think you forgot to add the database details

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Now I have added link for images of database.You can check databse by clicking on those urls.

Comment: So you want to list the testUsers that are also in the users list. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes,you are correct. I want list of test users who are also in users list